# Expected a string but returning a number

Tags: c

This program is intended to return a string, when passing command line arguments it works as intended, however when arguments are inserted manually it returns a number instead of a string and I can't identify why this is happening. It seems I did something wrong while printing the string with "printf ("The modified expression is: %s", s2);", since it never prints the intended string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

    int nv(char *s1, char c1)
{
    int i,count=0;
    i=0;
    if (s1 != NULL)
    {
    while(s1[i]!=0)
    {
        if (s1[i]==c1)
        ++count;
        ++i;
    }
}
    return count;
}
int po(char *s1, char c1)
{
    int i;

    i=0;
    if (s1 != NULL)
    {
        while(s1[i]!=0)
        {
        if (s1[i]==c1)
            return i;        
        ++i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

char *s(char *s1, char c1, char c2)
{
    int i;
    char expression[256];
    char rep1[256];
    char rep2[256];
    if (s1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("No command line arguments! Please insert the expression to modify.\n");
        scanf(" %s",expression);
        s1=expression;
        printf("Insert the character to replace.\n");
        scanf(" %s",rep1);
        c1=*rep1;
        printf("Insert the replacement character.\n");
        scanf(" %s",rep2);
        c2=*rep2;
    }

    i=0;
    if (s1 != NULL)
    {
        while(s1[i]!=0)
        {
        if (s1[i]==c1)
        s1[i]=c2;
        ++i;
    }
}
return s1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x,y,i = 0;
    char *s1 = NULL,c1 = '\0',c2 = '\0';
    char *s2 = NULL;
    if(argc!=1)
    {
    x = nv(argv[1], argv[2][0]);
    y = po(argv[1], argv[2][0]);
    s1 = s(argv[1], argv[2][0], argv[3][0]);

    printf("i=%d, count=%d, po=%d\n\n",i,x,y);

    printf("\n %s \n\n", s1);
    printf("\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        x = nv(argv[1], argv[2][0]);
        y = po(argv[1], argv[2][0]);
        s2 = s(s1,c1,c2);

        printf ("The modified expression is: %s", s2);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want this: `printf(s1,"\n %s \n\n");`. Swap the arguments to `printf`

Comment: Since `expression`  is a local address, it is invalid outside the scope.

Comment: `if(argc!=1){ ... } else { ...}` : The else-block is executed when it is `argc==1`. In that case,  `argv[1]`  will be `NULL`. And `argv[2][0]` is invalid access.